# Error with SharedPreferences in two activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities and I need to get access to `SharedPreferences` from any of them. I try in my MainActivity OnCreate:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("shkatovl.btandroid", MODE_PRIVATE);
if(!prefs.contains("CMD1")){
prefs.edit().putString("CMD1", "").apply();
}
```

And in another activity:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("shkatovl.btandroid", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I have an error on the last string. What's the problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MODE_PRIVATE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) is member of [`Context`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). Depending on where you use it, you must prefix it with its class name, e.g.

```
...getSharedPreferences("shkatovl.btandroid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```